# set up wamp server to run on lan

Tags: mysql, lan, wamp, vb.net

I have 2 computers. Both with w7 as os. I have installed wampserver on one of them.
I have mysql database on wampserver.
Then I have made a vb.net program to connect to mysql database. I have put the program on both computers.
What I want to do is for those two programs to see the same database that is on one computer. For them to be able to add, delete, update that 1 database. 
How do I do that? How do I network the mysql database? Do I also have to install wampserver on the other computer?
What do I do? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need WAMP to access a MySQL database from a VB.Net program. If you're not using the Apache web server or programming in PHP, you can just install MySQL by itself.

For your VB.Net program to connect, you'll need to 1) make sure both computers are on the same subnet,  2) properly configure MySQL to allow multiple connections over TCP/IP, and 3) design your VB.Net program to accept the correct network connection information to connect to the database. This will be at leat an IP address & login credentials.

If you are fixed on using VB.Net, I think you'll have better overall success using IIS if you need a web server, and SQL Server for your database. A lightweight version of IIS is available with some versions of Windows 7, and SQL Server Express is a good option to get started with.

Comment: I'm really having problems when I enable IIS. wampserver won't work.
And what should I do with your #2 answer

Comment: Do you need a webserver? You're question implies that you aren't using one, since Apache doesn't use VB.Net. If you don't need one, don't use one. I can't help you with the MySQL config; it's been a while since I've used it.